# Authorization callback URL from github not working, looping same page

Tags: github, oauth, callback

So i'm building a website that requires the user to be github authenticated in order to create and publish blog posts via the netify cms.

so in github i've added the application.

the homepage is set as:

```
https://example.netlify.com
```

in order to reach the admin area of the site to post blogs and such the user must navigate to

https://example.netlify.com/admin/ and authenticate via github.

now the authentication part is working, i am logging into my github account but it loops back to the oauth page but with a weird url:

```
https://example.netlify.com/admin/?error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=The+redirect_uri+MUST+match+the+registered+callback+URL+for+this+application.&error_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.github.com%2Fapps%2Fmanaging-oauth-apps%2Ftroubleshooting-authorization-request-errors%2F%23redirect-uri-mismatch&state=5d971eb88a5073cf804e90d5#/collections/blog
```

I've set my Authorization callback URL to:

```
https://example.netlify.com/admin/#/collections/blog
```

which is where the user should log in to, in order to post blogs and articles

so why does it keep looping? i've obviously set up a field incorrectly, i'm assuming that my Authorization callback URL to is incorrect?

Comment: Have you tried reading the error in the "weird url" it tells you what the problem is

Comment: yes i have, and i do not understand what it means, if you know and could provide an example, then that would be helpful.  what must match

Answer (score 0):

> Error = redirect_uri_mismatch
>   error_description=The+redirect_uri+MUST+match+the+registered+callback+URL+for+this+application.
>   error_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.github.com%2Fapps%2Fmanaging-oauth-apps%2Ftroubleshooting-authorization-request-errors%2F%23redirect-uri-mismatch

The main clue in this error message is redirect_uri_mismatch if you take that and google it you will begin to understand the problem.  Part of the security with Identity servers is that the Redirct uri, that being the redirect uri that the Identity server returns your authorization to must be registered on the idnetiy server itself.  Someone cant just send a request on behalf of your application and get the authorization back on their own site.

So what ever redirect uri you are sending in your application needs to be registered over on Github for the authorization to work.  Its currently not.

You can read more about it here [Troubleshooting OAuth App access token request errors](https://developer.github.com/apps/managing-oauth-apps/troubleshooting-oauth-app-access-token-request-errors/)

Comment: thanks for the reponse, where might i find my Redirect Uri, the codebase I am working from is a premade CMS. and can't see anything relating to a redirect url in the code or something to do with Netlify? I hope you can appreciate that I am a complete noob. thanks!

Comment: Your going to have to look for it its in your authorization code.  Where ever you are calling it your probably sending a redirect uri.